# Forward local port to remote host telnet port

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, telnet

I'm trying to forward a local port to a remote telnet host. Something like this.

MyHost -----> |2222 Proxy |------> |23 Destination |

- **MyHost**: I'm on a Windows PC.
- **Proxy**: Is a linux box which I control.
- **Destination**: Is a custom device which only accepts connections via
  telnet.

My ultimate goal is to telnet to **Destination** from **MyHost** through **Proxy**.
I've read several guides but can't seem to get the right command to run on Proxy to have this work.

Also, if it's not possible to do this via ssh forwarding, would netcat cut it? Lack of encryption is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the proxy is running iptables, it is as simple as

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d proxy.ip.add.ress -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination des.tina.tion.IP:23`

Comment: Wouldn't I have to also allow the other way around?

Comment: Yes, you would need to allow ESTABLISHED traffic back in.

Comment: Nevermind, I ended up using: `netcat -L destination:23 -p 8888` on proxy. Thanks a lot for your help though.

Comment: good luck when that dies.

Comment: What do you mean, will it leave a mess behind?